# Relating username table with another table in android studio using SQlite Databse

Tags: java, android

I want to display a guest list inserted by the user under a specific user and so i want to know how do I relate the user ID to the guest ID.

I want to attach the user id to the guest id, please help me out.
Can you please help me out as to how to add a foreign key or a third table and how to relate it using a query.

My database code is listed below:

```
package com.mangal.myapplication.ui.utils;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.mangal.myapplication.ui.Models.GuestModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //User Login and Register columns
    public static final String DB_NAME ="event.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="users";
    public static final String COL_ID="ID";

    // Guest Table columns
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_GUESTS="Guests";
    private static final String COL_GUESTS_ID="ID_GUESTS";
    private static final String COL_NAME_GUESTS="name";
    private static final String COL_STATUS_GUESTS="status";

    // SQL statement of the guests table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_GUESTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_GUESTS + "("
            + COL_GUESTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL_NAME_GUESTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_STATUS_GUESTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "

            +");";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table users(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, password TEXT)");
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_GUESTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists users");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME_GUESTS);

        onCreate(db);


    }

    public boolean addUser(String username,String pwd){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username",username);
        contentValues.put("password",pwd);
        long result= db.insert("users",null,contentValues);
        if (result==-1) return false;
        else return true;
    }
      

    public boolean inserttGuest(GuestModel model){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME_GUESTS , model.getGuest());
        values.put(COL_STATUS_GUESTS , 0);
        long res= db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null , values);
        if(res == -1){
            Log.d("not added","the guest was not added");
            return false;
        }else {
            Log.d("added", "the guest was added");
            return true;
        }
    }


    public void updateStatus(int id , int status){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_STATUS_GUESTS , status);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME , values , "ID=?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }


    public List<GuestModel> getAllGuests(String User_name){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<GuestModel> modelList=new ArrayList<>();


        try {
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME , null , null , null , null , null , null);
            if (cursor !=null){
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        GuestModel guest= new GuestModel();
                        guest.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
                        guest.setGuest(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME_GUESTS)));
                        guest.setStatus(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_STATUS_GUESTS)));
                        modelList.add(task);

                    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return modelList;
    }

}
```

Comment: how exactly do you want the relationship btwn the user id and guest id?

Answer (score 0):

since you never specified about how you want the relationship,here I am assuming you want to link the guest to a certain user id
first of all to have relationships based on foreign keys, you need to enable foreign keys on sqlite for every connection as by  default its currently disabled.

```
String enable_foreign_keys ="PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
```

secondly is how you create your tables .
Guest table change :

> private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_GUESTS = "CREATE TABLE "
>
> - TABLE_NAME_GUESTS + "("
>   + COL_GUESTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
>   + COL_NAME_GUESTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
>   + COL_STATUS_GUESTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+");";

to :

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_GUESTS = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME_GUESTS + "("+ COL_GUESTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL_NAME_GUESTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_STATUS_GUESTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(ID));";
```

Meaning every time you insert a guest with user_id,UserID must exist in the users table
if you want to do a many to many relationship ,consider creating another table with columns user_id and guest.there, many users can be linked to one guest and vice verser.